# View space positions from depth in DirectX orthographic camera

Tags: c++, 3d, shader, directx

I have a depth texture and I'm trying to output the view space positions on the screen.

I'm using an orthgraphic camera.

here is the result
[image]

```
float3 position_in_view_space(float2 uv)
{
    float z = depth_tex.SampleLevel(depth_sampler, uv, 0.0f).x;
    // Get x/w and y/w from the viewport position
    float x = uv.x * 2 - 1;
    float y = (1 - uv.y) * 2 - 1;
    float4 vProjectedPos = float4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
    // Transform by the inverse projection matrix
    float4 vPositionVS = mul(vProjectedPos, inv_proj);  
    // Divide by w to get the view-space position
    return vPositionVS.xyz / vPositionVS.w;  
    
}

float3 position_from =position_in_view_space(tex_coord.xy);
output.color = float4(position_from, 1.0);
return output;
```

Comment: please clarify what mesh are you rendering and what is UV coordinates it's using? If you are sampling depth-texture by this uv, then you don't need to divide output XY by W, because they are already in view space.

Comment: @AlexBakanov I guess the main problem is I'm using orthographic camera, and the above code is for perspective camera